# Java клиент для WCF Web Service с WSHttpBinding

Tags: java, c#, wcf, wsdl

Я пытаюсь написать java клиент для WCF веб сервиса, написанного на C#. При использовании BasicHttpBinding клиент спокойно подключается к сервису и отправляет/получает данные без проблем. Если же использовать WSHttpBinding, то клиент не справляется. Я уже прочитал много подобных вопросов/проблем на английском stackoverflow, из чего я сделал вывод, что java попросту не поддерживает стандартные протоколы WSHttpBinding (ну или как-то так).

Мне обязательно нужно, чтобы данные между клиентом и сервисом передавались в зашифрованном виде, причем шифрование должно быть встроенным (требование задания).

Могу ли я как-то все-таки подружить java с WSHttpBinding от WCF? На англ. stackoverflow довольно часто советовали библиотеку Metro, но советовали всегда в контексте NetBeans IDE (я использую IntelliJ IDEA). Кроме того, туториал на сайте библиотеки не очень дружелюбный, и честно говоря, разбираться с ним не хочется.

Моя другая идея - можно ли настроить свой binding (что-то похожее было на англ. stackoverflow), который будет выполнять шифрование сам, но при условии, что клиент пройдет аутентификацию? Если да, то как?

Comment: Ох, сколько воображения надо, чтобы понять, о че  вопрос. Проиллюстрируйте свою архитектуру кодом со стороны клиента и сервера, чтобы без воображения понятно стало. Тогда шанс получить нужный ответ существенно возрастёт.

Comment: @aepot, приводить архитектуру не вижу смысла. Есть wcf веб сервис, у которого есть 1 метод - сложение двух целых чисел. Весь остальной код сервиса генерирует VisualStudio, а мне остается только запустить на сервере. Клиент генерируется за счет WSDL файла веб сервиса. В итоге, я лишь пытаюсь вызвать методы на клиенте, но при WSHttpBinding не работает.